# MKPointAnnotation: title always visible. Is it possible?

Tags: ios5, dictionary, mkmapview, mkannotation, mapkit

My code for adding a marker and title is this:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = coord;
annotationPoint.title = currentTitle;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

Is it possible to show title on marker immediately after marker is shown and always visible ?
Thanks much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = coord;
annotationPoint.title = currentTitle;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:NO];
```

OR

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)map didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{

    for (MKAnnotationView *av in views){

        if ([av.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]){
            [mapView selectAnnotation:av.annotation animated:NO];
            break;
        }

    }

}
```